# Undefined offset: 1 error coming from this line7

Tags: php, html

Every time I try to run my code I am getting a 'Notice: Undefined offset: 1 Error

specifically coming from this line:

```
$acmark= $summary[1][1] += $student[$row][2] / 25;
```

I am new to PHP and would like to get this working with the least amount of changes possible. I  have uploaded the full source code to Pastebin to make for easier viewing.

http://pastebin.com/Ur8u673V

Thanks in advance guys, Luke.

Comment: What's the output of ```print_r($summary);``` and ```print_r($student);``` near the offending line?

Comment: results here, I don't have a clue whats going on.. http://pastebin.com/NjkyGHD9

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code in your paste, you're initialising `$summary` to an empty array, and never actually adding anything to it before attempting to read the data. It's equivalent to:

```
$summary = array();
// ...
$acmark = $summary[1][1] += $student[$row][2] / 25; // $summary[1] isn't defined
```

Comment: when I added that it took away several other errors, basically the only reason its there.

Comment: ```$summary``` is both written to and read from in the loop in that paste. It looks pretty tricky to reason about, though.

Comment: @jameslafferty I think it's easy enough to see that the first time a read attempt is made on `$summary[1][1]`, `$summary` is an empty array.

Comment: Ah... you're right @GeorgeBrighton... I scanned that ```+=``` as ```=```;

Answer (score 0):

Agree with George - you're initializing `$summary` as an array, but the offset starts at `0`. Since you're incrementing in a loop, change line 140 to:

`$acmark = $summary[][] += $student[$row][2] / 25;`

That will eliminate the notice. You can apply the same solution to the other lines with undefined offsets as well to resolve the other notices.

Consider using an associative array(s) with `foreach` loops so the array keys are more meaningful. Associative arrays are easier to use and support the idea of using [self-documenting code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting)

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the reply. When I replace line 140 with your code it get rids of the error but also breaks the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

i think u should set value of array first (maybe with 0), because if undefines is meaning that array is null value (null is different with 0)

add this code after $summary = array(); like below

```
$summary=array();

//additional code
for($sum=0; $sum<6; $sum++)
    $summary[$sum][1]=0;

for($row=0; $row<25; $row++){
   .
   .
   .
```

Comment: Hello man, again this fixed the errors but broke the actual calculation at the bottom of the page..

Comment: are you have try that??, maybe you can try first, without using rand value,.. because i don't think that will be broke the actual calculation

Comment: i have try 2 way that i sent before,,, buat option is not working.. but option one is working.. i will not broke you actual calculation..

Comment: Hey man tried the first method there! Got it working! thank you very much all help was appreciated :)

Comment: glad for help.. please accept the answer if the answer is correct by clicking check mark below vote down.. thanks